# What are some good options for vertically-scaling a comet server? Is 500k / server realistic?

Tags: ajax, comet

These guys reckon they can support 1 million comet clients on an 'entry level' server:
http://migratory.ro/

Are there any other similarly vertically scalable comet servers out there that anyone can recommend? Benchmarks would be great. Preferably open source.

I want to know if half a million comet clients connected to a single server is going to be realistic with anything other than migratory, or if they're just 'cooking the books' even...

Thanks all

Comment: Would something at this scale best be served with a custom libev-based server?

Comment: More evidence that 1m concurrent users is indeed possible: http://www.metabrew.com/article/a-million-user-comet-application-with-mochiweb-part-3

Comment: A more humble attempt, using node: http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/d19df83c7fd1f3ca/7db52e742d3c58c8?#7db52e742d3c58c8

Answer (score 1):

Migratory Push Server http://migratory.ro/ can support 1 million comet clients on an 'entry level' server, as you can check this on the benchmark they posted on their site:

http://migratory.ro/data/Migratory-Push-Server-Performance-Benchmarks.pdf

Cheers